# How do you drag an image under higher element using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need help with being able to drag an image thats underneath an overlying png mask which has areas that allow the image beneath to show through. I want to be able to move the image beneath the mask around but keep the mask stationary. is this possible to accomplish, if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how cross-browser it needs to be, but you can use [`pointer-events:none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events)

http://jsfiddle.net/dvjfv/

```
.overlay {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The PNG mask will always intercept the click event if it is layered on top of the image underneath. There is simply no way around that. However, you can certainly detect a `mousedown` event on the mask and use that to cause the window's `mousemove` event to adjust the position of the underlying image. You would then use a `mouseup` event to end the drag (i.e. the window's `mousemove` event would no longer affect the position of the image).